# Configuring Rasberry Pi 2b for WiFi adapter monitoring fails upon reboot

Tags: networking, pi-2, wireless-adapter, monitoring

I've been using [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-network-scanner/) to configure my Raspberry Pi model 2b and turn my WiFi usb adapter into monitor mode.

To note I used [this github repo](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au) to get my WiFi usb adapter working on my Raspberry Pi 2b.

I follow the following steps from [the guide:](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-network-scanner/)

```
pi@Test:~ $ iw dev
phy#0
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 3
                wdev 0x1
                addr 00:c0:ca:a8:e0:61
                type managed
                channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2412 MHz
                txpower 20.00 dBm
```

As you can see my WiFi adapter is `wlan0` under `phy#0`, because the Raspberry Pi 2 doesn't have it's own built WiFi card.

```
    pi@Test:~ $ iw phy phy0 info
    Wiphy phy0
            max # scan SSIDs: 9
            max scan IEs length: 2304 bytes
            max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
            max # match sets: 0
            Retry short limit: 7
            Retry long limit: 4
            Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
            Supported Ciphers:
                    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                    * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
                    * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
            Available Antennas: TX 0x2 RX 0x2
            Supported interface modes:
                     * IBSS
                     * managed
                     * AP
                     * monitor
                     * P2P-client
                     * P2P-GO
```

You can see on the third to last line you can see that my WiFi adapter does indeed support `* monitor` mode

Now I modify the interfaces file under `pi@Test:~ $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and add these lines to it:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
pre-up iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
pre-up iw dev wlan0 del
pre-up ifconfig mon0 up
```

Now the entire interfaces file looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
pre-up iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
pre-up iw dev wlan0 del
pre-up ifconfig mon0 up
```

However when I run `pi@Test:~ $ sudo reboot` I get the following errors after leaving it running for 10 minutes:

[image]

If I switch the Raspberry Pi off, remove the usb WiFi adapter and remove:

```
 allow-hotplug wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet manual
 pre-up iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
 pre-up iw dev wlan0 del
 pre-up ifconfig mon0 up
```

from the interfaces file. I'm able to reboot succesfully and re-attatch my usb WiFi adapter to start again from the first step in this quesiton.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't update the interfaces file. It's set-up for use with dhcpcd not network manager.

Comment: @Dougie Okay, what do I need to do instead then? Sorry i'm new to this.

Comment: Use the dhcpcd hooks as per https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.html that should have less risk of breaking your networking.